# HTTP/1.1 protocol testing tool

Tags: http, testing

Currently I'm implementing a HTTP server targeted at extremely constraint environments (I'd loved to use something readily available, but there was nothing matching my needs).

The HTTP/1.1 protocol is a tricky beast with lots of caveats (the RFC is one thing, but the actual specification is "HTTP is whatever Apache accepts" ;) )

I'd like my HTTP server to be as conformant as possible and for that I must test it of course. So I'm looking for a tool that can reliably and reproducible craft HTTP queries, most importantly also the uncommon cases, like Chunked Transfer + Multipart POST in a single query (my attempts at making curl, wget, Firefox, Chromium or Opera creating such a query were fruitless).

TL;DR: I need a tool for testing HTTP/1.1 protocol server implementations.

Comment: Are you talking about WebSockets as well? I think that you won't find a tool suitable for your case and you will end up writing your own tool. But this should not be a difficult task.

Comment: @freakish: Just the HTTP/1.1 protocol as specified by RFC2616 – anything built on of that is out of the scope right now, for me. Later maybe it might become interesting, but so far it's just what written in the RFC what I want to test.